# Com montar uma query no Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-eloquent

Como faço para colocar essa query no Eloquent?

```
SELECT juros FROM tbl_parcelas WHERE 2500 BETWEEN tbl_parcelas.valor_min AND tbl_parcelas.valor_max
```

CÓDIGO:

```
DB::table('SELECT juros FROM tbl_parcelas WHERE 2500 BETWEEN tbl_parcelas.valor_min AND tbl_parcelas.valor_max');
```

Comment: Olá André, o que você tentou até o momento? Está com dificuldade em alguma parte específica da query?

Comment: Eu não sei exatamente como utilizar a sintaxe do Eloquent para esta query

Comment: Solução: DB::select("SELECT juros FROM parcelas WHERE $valor BETWEEN valor_min AND valor_max");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução para este caso:

```
$valor = 2500;
DB::select("SELECT juros FROM parcelas WHERE $valor BETWEEN valor_min AND valor_max");
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer isso de duas maneiras, a primeira seria utilizando o `Model` dessa tabela e a segunda seria usando a `facade` `DB` do laravel, no caso essa segunda opção foi a sua tentativa.

```
// Exemplo utilizando model
$valor = 2500;
$juros = Parcela::where('valor_min' '>=', $valor)
                ->where('valor_max', '<=', $valor)
                ->select('juros')
                ->get();

// Exemplo usando DB
$juros = DB::table('tbl_parcelas')->where('valor_min' '>=', $valor)
                                  ->where('valor_max', '<=', $valor)
                                  ->select('juros')
                                  ->get();
```

Comment: Kayo Bruno, obrigado pela dica porém dessa forma retorna null,

Comment: Solução: 
DB::select("SELECT juros FROM parcelas WHERE 2500 BETWEEN valor_min AND valor_max");

Comment: Se retorna null é pq não tem registro q satisfaça a query.

Comment: Verdade, muito obrigado me ajudou bastante resolver. Grato.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo tempo que está o post já deve ter resolvido, mas eu faria assim:

```
 $juros = DB::table('parcelas')
                 ->select('juros')
                 ->whereRaw("? between valor_min and valor_max", [$valor])
                 ->get();
```

Ou tambem:

```
 $juros = DB::table('parcelas')
                 ->select('juros')
                 ->whereColumn([
                     ['valor_min', '>=', $valor],
                     ['valor_max', '<=', $valor]
                  ])->get();
```